# How to copy a word document section-by-section

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have to update a word document to the most recent company template but that task is not so easy as it looks.
According to [this](http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/how-to-attach-a-template-to-a-word-2010-document.html) site all it takes is to perform the described steps but after doing it the document remained as it was before, for instance, the footer and header remained the same, that is, they  were not updated to the ones set in the new template.
After spending some time on how to accomplish that task I realized that both the header and footer are not related to the template but to the underlying section instead.
Then, I took another approach that boiled down to copy only the section content without the header and the footer to the already defined sections in the new template and apparently it gets the job done.
Therefore, I would like to know if there is any way to perform these section copying automatically - **through VBA** - or even other better approach I can take ?

Comment: How long and how complex is the template? What do you need to reproduce: headers, footers, styles, textboxes, some standard content?

Comment: From the old template I just need to reproduce the content as well as the styles attached to it and maybe a few bookmarks.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I wouldn't use VBA unless the task was huge. By the time you've created some code, run it, failed, re-written it, you'll probably find that it could have been completed faster manually, especially if, as appears, this is a one-off job. Of course, if you encounter a task which you realise is repetitive and time-consuming, then you might make use of the Macro Recorder.

I obviously don't have the documents in front of me but:

- Do a little planning. Work out how many sections there should be, and of what type (Next Page Section Break, etc.).
- Use `Draft View` and Goto (Ctrl-G), Section to help discover them.
- Scribble down an outline of what the final headers/ footers should contain.
- If applicable, note down the `Style` names from both templates and work out which ones need to be replaced.
- (I would) work on a copy of the new template and copy the content from the old one. This will copy the styles from the old template at the same time. This might be the wrong way round for you - you'll have to decide this. Try both and see which is easiest to work with.
- You can use the `Replace` dialog (Ctrl-H) to swap one style for another.
- Display the Styles Window as well (Ctrl-Alt-Shift-S).
- From the `Styles Window` you can show the `Style Manager`. From here, and Import/Export, you can Delete, Rename and Copy Styles. Be careful about deleting styles as it is difficult to gauge what they will default to.

I would leave Headers and Footers until (second to) last and, when doing so, start at the beginning of the document and progress *forward-only* through the Sections, copying from the old template if necessary.

I would leave Bookmarks until the very end; by that time it should be easy to Insert them. If you have copied content from the old document then it should have carried the Bookmarks across as well, so it just a question of making sure that they are still in the right place.

Again, I don't have the templates in front of me, so I appreciate that some of this advice may not be relevant.

Hint: It might take a few attempts to get this right. If you get stuck at some point bear it mind that it might be better to start over - if it gets messy it is sometimes tricky to recover.

Comment: BTW That Dummies book is over-simplifying the task. It is really assuming that you have a blank document that you simply want to attach a template (some styles) to. If you just wanted to copy some styles you could just copy/paste/delete the entire content of the other document - all its styles would then be available.

Comment: Andy thanks for the reply. However this task is something that will be needed quite often in the near future, so there is actually a point in automate this task. With that said, the template structure between the two templates is quite similar except for some images and other small details. Thus, the sections that exist in the old template also exist in the new one - new headers and footers are already set- but they have no content at all. All in all,  if I could copy the text from the old template sections and past it onto the new ones that would accomplish the job...

Comment: So you can record some macros, explore the code that it creates. You'll need to study VBA.

Comment: That's precisely it I'm looking for, the code snippet that allows me to copy a section content without bring the header and footer attached. If someone could provide me that code or even some pointer on the subject I would appreciate it.